# Variable Scope outside jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to identify the height of a div element in HTML, but I am not able to access the value outside of the function.  This is the jQuery:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) { 
    $(function() {
        $tmp_cont = $('<div></div>');
        $tmp_cont.html($content);
        $tmp_cont.hide();
        $('body').append($tmp_cont);

        var $height = $tmp_cont.height();

        alert ($height);
    });
})(jQuery);

alert ($height);
```

The first alert function works, but the second throws and error with `$height` as undefined. How can I retain the value of `$height`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just remove the `var` like this:

```
$height = $tmp_cont.height();
```

If you want a global variable, leave off the `var`, or more explicitly:

```
window.$height = $tmp_cont.height();
```

Or if you still want it local, just declare it higher up, like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
var $height;
(function($) { 
    $(function() {
        $tmp_cont = $('<div></div>');
        $tmp_cont.html($content);
        $tmp_cont.hide();
        $('body').append($tmp_cont);

        $height = $tmp_cont.height();
        alert ($height);
    });
})(jQuery);
alert ($height);
```

Comment: wow.. that works thanks, can you please explain me the difference of using var and not using it?

Comment: @atif089 - Pretty simple here...without `var` you get a variable declared in the global score (`window`) instead of a local one :)

Comment: You should always use var, even if you declare it in global scope. Otherwise (with accidental-globals) you can get weird errors in IE when you try to use a variable with the same name as an element on the page.